# Visual Studio / C++: Build of non-dependant project built on launching debug mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, build, dependencies, solution

I have a visual studio solution which has several projects written in C++. Some of the projects build executables and some are libraries. They are all statically linked.

Lets say the names of the projects are: 
 - ExecutableA 
 - ExecutableB 
 - LibA
 - LibB

ExecutableA and ExecutableB projects depend on LibA and LibB, but not on each other. Currently, when I start debugging ExecutableA (usually by pressing 'F5'), it wants to build ExecutableB before running. I assumed the Project dependcies were setup incorrectly, but ExecutableA does not seem to be set as dependant on ExecutableB. What other settings could be causing this behaviour? I did not experience this behaviour until we migrated to VS2012, so I'm wondering if there is perhaps a settingwhich has a different default value in VS2012 compared to VS2010?

Note: I'm sure this question has been asked and answered before, but I can't seem to find the right way of phrasing this question as a search to find the answer!

Comment: Can you try checking `Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run->Only build startup projetcs...`?

Comment: Thats definitely the setting I was looking for. I had mistakenly assumed it would be a project specific setting. Thanks for you help!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer then for future reference / visitors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the box

> Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run->
>   Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cyhcc7zc.aspx